# What is this syntax using new followed by a list inside braces?

Tags: c#, syntax

Ive just seen a piece of code that uses a generic list class to instantiate itself in the following manner:

```
var foo = new List<string>(){"hello", "goodbye"};
```

The curly braces after the contructor are especially confusing. It reminds me somewhat of

```
var bar = new string[]{"hi","bye"};
```

but in the past i've wouldve always used:

```
var foo = new List<string>(new []{"hello", "goodbye"});
```

Has anybody got a link explaining the syntax in the first line of code? I wouldnt even know where to begin with googling it.

Comment: The fact that the "confusing" syntax immediately reminded you of the *identical feature for arrays* is potentially an indication that it really wasn't that confusing at all, no?  We chose that syntax very carefully so that it would lead you to have precisely the intuition that you did have.

Comment: @maxp "In the past", you were initializing a List<string> by invoking a constructor that takes IEnumerable<T> and using array initializer syntax to create an anonymous collection, creating two references to the same collection.  TBH I don't know why the compiler doesn't optimize the syntax in line 1 to line 3 - surely it knows that that the object generated by 'new[]' that gets passed into the List<string> constructor can't be referred to independantly in any other way, and is therefore not necessary to keep alive.

Comment: @ValAkkapeddi: How should the *compiler team* know what the person who wrote `List<T>` is going to do with that object? The compiler has no special knowledge that any particular `List<T>` constructor does or does not do anything special with the array passed to it.

Comment: @ValAkkapeddi the array initializer syntax does not create two references to the same collection; rather, it creates an array and then passes that to the `List<T>` constructor.  The elements of the array are then, if I recall correctly, copied into the list's own internal array; the first array is then eligible for garbage colelction.

Comment: Please don't use " (c#)" in your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

here you go. The keyword is "Array Initializers".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx

or rather "Collection Initializers"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I see that these collection initializers are standard on any class that implements `iEnumerable.`

Comment: the community content on the second link discusses that a little... cannot confirm yet... wait, yes, there is says it in the docs.

Comment: @maxp that's not true.  The compiler converts a collection initializers to calls to the type's Add method (see my answer for more details).  A type could implement IEnumerable without having an Add method; collection initializers could not be used with that type.  For example, `System.String` implements IEnumerable, but has no `Add` method.

Comment: then this is a confusing sentence in the docs: Collection initializers let you specify one or more element intializers when you initialize a collection class that implements IEnumerable.

Comment: @mindandmedia yes, it is! I recall Eric Lippert writing a couple of months ago that an early design for collection initializers required the type to implement *ICollection*, but that design was abandoned in favor of the more flexible "Add method" approach.  When I read about that, I did some testing like the example in my answer.

Comment: @phoog i dont know what to think anymore, i just upvoted you, but your code doesn't seem to compile...

Comment: @mindandmedia: There are *two* requirements: the type must implement `IEnumerable` and there must be an `Add` method.

Comment: @Eric Thank you, that makes sense, since IEnumerable has no method Add()...as a side question, how did you get onto this post so quickly? (gotta love realtime)

Comment: @mindandmedia I edited my answer to correct it; thanks for keeping me on my toes :)

Comment: @phoog it was maxp, who compiled the code and you already got my upvote. thanks for caring to fix your answer

Answer (score 37):

As others have pointed out, that is a collection initializer. Some other features you might not be aware of that were added to C# 3:

- A collection initializer constructor may omit the parentheses if the argument list is empty. So `new List<int> { 10, 20, 30 }` is fine.
- An array initialized with an array initializer may in some cases omit the type. For example, `var myInts = new[] { 10, 20, 30};` infers that `myInts` is `int[]`.
- Objects may be initialized using a similar *object initializer* syntax. `var c = new Customer() { Name = "Fred" };` is the same as `var temp = new Customer(); temp.Name = "Fred"; var c = temp;`

The point of these features is to (1) make more things that used to require statements into things that require only expressions; LINQ likes things to be expressions, and (2) to enable richer type inference, particularly for anonymous types.

Finally: there has been some confusion in some of the answers and comments regarding what is required for a collection initializer. To be used with a collection initializer the type must (1) implement `IEnumerable` (so that we know it is a collection) and (2) have an `Add` method (so that we can add stuff to it.)

See

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2006/10/10/what-is-a-collection_3f00_.aspx

for additional thoughts on the design of the feature.

Answer (score 17):

This is a *collection initializer*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

The type so initialized must implement `IEnumerable` and have an `Add` method.  The items in the curly-brace list are passed to the add method; different items in the list could be passed to different `Add` methods.  If there's an `Add` overload with more than one argument, you put the multiple arguments in a comma-separated list enclosed in curly braces.

For example:

```
class MyWeirdCollection : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(int i) { /*...*/ }
    public void Add(string s) { /*...*/ }
    public void Add(int i, string s) { /*...*/ }

    //IEnumerable implementation omitted for brevity
}
```

This class could be initialized thus:

```
var weird = new MyWeirdCollection { 1, "Something", {5, "Something else"} };
```

This compiles to something like this:

```
var temp = new MyWeirdCollection();
temp.Add(1);
temp.Add("Something");
temp.Add(5, "Something else");
var weird = temp;
```

In [his blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2006/10/10/what-is-a-collection_3f00_.aspx) (link posted by Eric Lippert in the comments), Mads Torgersen expresses this concisely:

> The list you provide is not a “list of elements to add”, but a “list of sets of arguments to Add methods”.  ...[W]e do separate overload resolution against Add methods for each entry in the list.

Comment: This code wont compile.
`Cannot initialize type 'MyWeirdCollection' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable`

Comment: @maxp: You are correct; in order to be used with a collection initializer a type must have an `Add` method *and* implement `IEnumerable`. The reason is: we discovered that almost every mutable collection has and `Add` method and implements `IEnumerable`. Types that implement `Add` but are not `IEnumerable` tend to be arithmetic classes, not collection classes.

Comment: @mindandmedia Collection and object initializers were added in C#3.0

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2006/10/10/what-is-a-collection_3f00_.aspx for some thoughts.

Comment: @maxp I remembered incorrectly; I forgot about the IEnumerable requirement. I edited the post to add it; thanks for checking.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks for the link; I'd never read that blog post before.

Comment: This is a truly weird collection. It shows a good implementation however. +1

Comment: @AlexEssilfie thanks for the compliment.  I would add that I omitted the implementation of the add methods because it was too weird :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). You can use it on collections with an `Add` method.

The pair of parentheses before the curly braces is optional.

This is very convenient, because you can use it on collections other than lists, for example on dictionaries:

```
var x = new Dictionary<int,string> {{1, "hello"}, {2, "world"}};
```

This lets you avoid a lengthier initialization sequence:

```
var x = new Dictionary<int,string>();
x.Add(1, "hello");
x.Add(2, "world");
```

Answer (score 2):

In the third line of code you provided you are making a new string array, and then passing that string array to the list.  The list will then add each of those items to the list.  This involves the extra overhead of allocating the array, populating it, and then discarding it.

There is a mechanism for a class to define how to use Collection Initializers to populate itself.  (See the other answers)  I have never found the need to utilize this for my own classes, but existing data structures such as List, Dictionary, often define them, and they are useful to use.